# Does mahram at dunyah also mahram at jannah?

Tags: jannah

Asalamoalikum!
I read about a fatwa in which the mufti writes that a man will be allowed to marry his mahram (sister nephew etc) except mother and daughter in jannah.
He didn't mentioned any ayah or hadees

Comment: Some scholars have reasoned that the prohibitions stemming from jealousy and conflict will not apply, such as the limit of having a maximum of four wives or the prohibition of marrying a woman and her sister simultaneously, or a woman and her niece simultaneously etc. Possibly the fatwa you read misinterpreted this.